# PHP GET Rows based on URL ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search function on my site which displays results from a MySQL db. Each search result is linked to a dynamic php page with the URL, i.e. /details.php?id=123.

I need the details.php page to get the ID (e.g 123) from the URL and then fetch all rows from the database with this ID, storing them in a variable for use later. I then need to be able to echo the rows at various points throughout the page to populate the content.

The code I have so far is:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("","","") or die("Database Error");
mysql_select_db("items",$db); 
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `items- table` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";  
$result = mysql_query($query); 
?>
```

I’m fairly new to PHP so not sure if the code above will get all rows based on the ID, and then how to echo the rows within divs on the page?

Comment: Come on,as it looks now this is a do stuff for me question

Comment: please note that mysql_ functions are deprecated and will soon be removed. It's better for you to move to mysqli_ functions or even better to move to PDO. Since you are still a newbie it won't be an issue.

Comment: better check the id with `is_numeric($id)` instead of escapestring

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysql_fetch_array()` OR `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function with while loop (if multiple rows there) OR without while loop if there is only one row.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `items- table` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";  
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<div>".$fetch['column_name']."</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am receiving an error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **url** on line 8?

Comment: There is problem in your query. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct. Just add something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<div>';
  foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
    echo $key.' = '.$value.'<br/>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
```